# mysql count distinct join on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

I am trying to count a distinct value in either of two rows. For instance, a table with columns fruit0, fruit1. I can get a count of the distinct values of either row, but I want a count of them combined (note this is a stupid contrived example).

Example:

```
id | fruit0 | fruit1
--------------------
0  | apple  | banana
1  | apple  | pear
2  | apple  | apple
3  | pear   | banana
```

I want something like:

```
fruit | count   
--------------
apple | 4
banana| 2
pear  | 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select fruit_name, count(*) 
FROM
(
   SELECT fruit0 as fruit_name
   FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fruit1 as fruit_name
   FROM table1
)aaa
GROUP BY fruit_name
```

Comment: :) yw. If you mark my answer as the one that helped you, I'll appreciate it.